# Higher order tensors Definition and notation issues

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

Reading this interesting short paper review https://haggaim.github.io/projects/universality/poster.pdf, I came across some notations/definitions that I'd like to understand better.

Let $G \le S_n$ any subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ and define the *action* of $G$ on $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as

$$g \cdot x := (x_{g^{-1}(1)} \, \dots \, , x_{g^{-1}(n)}) \, \, \, ,g \in G.$$

The action of $G$ on *tensors* $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n^k \times a}$ is defined as

$$(g \cdot X_{i_1, \dots i_k,j}) = X_{g^{-1}(i_1), \dots, g^{-1}(i_k), j}, \, \, g \in G.$$

Now how should I think about the object $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n^k \times a}$ ..?

if $k=1$ then I would have simply a **matrix** $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times a}$ representing a 2-rank tensor....? But why? I have a bit of confusion about this kind of notation.

Comment: If $k=1$ then you only have $1$ index to permute, so $g$ must be trivial: $g=(1)$. The only possible transformation is identity. The smallest non-trivial example would be $k=2$, where you can represent the tensor as a "stack" of $a$ ${n \times n}$ matrices. For $k = 2$ you get 2 possibilities: $g = (1,2)$  representing identity, and $g = (2,1)$, which acts on the tensor by transposing each of those $a$ matrices on the stack. The notation is a bit weird because usually in a tensor all indices have the same dimension (you would simply omit the single index $j$ of dimension $a$).